# How can I track changes to specific OneDrive folder under approot?

Tags: rest, onedrive

### State

I have a **personal OneDrive** and a registered application “**MyApplication**”. In the personal OneDrive, there is this structure:

```
/
 Apps
  MyApplication
   A_Subfolder
```

The id of “A_Subfolder” is `BLABLABLABLA!112`.

I can do an API GET for either `drive/root:/Apps/MyApplication/A_Subfolder` or `drive/items/BLABLABLABLA!112` and I successfully get info about the folder.

Now, I want to subscribe to changes for “A_Subfolder”. If I want to subscribe to changes to the “MyApplication” folder, I can do it by API POST to `/subscriptions` with payload:

```
{
"changeType": "updated",
"notificationUrl": "https://my.domain/my_webhook",
"resource": "/drive/special/approot",
"expirationDateTime": "2021-04-10T12:00:00Z",
"clientState": "myState"
}
```

After that, I get callbacks to my webhook.

### Question

I want to subscribe to changes to “A_Subfolder”. So **what do I need to supply as “resource” in the payload below** of the `/subscriptions` POST?

```
{
"changeType": "updated",
"notificationUrl": "https://my.domain/my_webhook",
"resource": "??????????????????",
"expirationDateTime": "2021-04-10T12:00:00Z",
"clientState": "myState"
}
```

What do I substitute for `"??????????????????"`?

### Additional history

In the [documentation for webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0), there are these two distinct paragraphs (“any” and “root” are italicized in the webpage):

> driveItem on OneDrive (personal)
> Changes to content within the hierarchy of *any* folder:
> `/users/{id}/drive/root`

and:

> driveItem on OneDrive for Business
> Changes to content within the hierarchy of the *root* folder:
> `/drives/{id}/root`
> `/users/{id}/drive/root`

This distinction between “any folder” and “root folder” makes me understand that I can subscribe to the changes of a specific folder in a personal OneDrive drive.  This is for a backend application that access some app folder in the user's drive, under the associated app root folder.

However, all attempts so far to subscribe to anything else than `drive/special/approot` have failed; other attempts with `drive/special/approot:/path/to/folder`, `drive/special/approot:path/to/folder`, and `drive/items/‹folder-id›` result in 4xx errors.

Do I understand incorrectly the documentation?  If not, how can I subscribe to a specific folder (including its subfolders; I have verified that this is the behavior, exactly as documented)?

PS In [Use the Microsoft Graph API to get change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) there is also this under “driveItem”:

> On a personal OneDrive, you can subscribe to the root folder or any subfolder in that drive.

PS2: in [Set up notifications for changes in user data - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#supported-resources) there is this:

> ‣ Content within the hierarchy of any folder driveItem on a user's personal OneDrive
> ‣ Content within the hierarchy of the root folder driveItem on OneDrive for Business

PS3 In [Create subscription - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#driveitem), there is this:

> On a personal OneDrive, you can subscribe to the root folder or any subfolder in that drive.
> On OneDrive for Business, you can subscribe to only the root folder.
> Change notifications are sent for the requested types of changes on
> the subscribed folder, or any file, folder, or other driveItem
> instances in its hierarchy. You cannot subscribe to drive or driveItem
> instances that are not folders, such as individual files.

So again: how do I specify the folder under the approot folder that I can subscribe to?